# Why wasn't Aldo Raine punished in Iglourious Basterds?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, inglourious-basterds

First time we meet Lt. Aldo Raine he is declaring:

[image]

> Nazi ain't got no humanity. They're the foot soldiers of a jew-hating, mass-murdering maniac and they need to be destroyed.

He is generalizing and seems to be as much of a bigot as the people he fights against, and in the end he humiliates Landa, has the last say and comes out something of a hero... By hero I mean that in the end he is the victor and has ended WWII which indirectly justifies his actions. No I am not talking about the 'swastika mutilation', I am saying that stating that 'All Nazis should be destroyed' is the same thing as stating that 'All Jews should be destroyed'. I think that saying that a group of people 'deserves to be destroyed' is inhumane.

Is there something I missed in the story or is there a hole in the plot and a murderer was made a hero?

Comment: Forget it Jake, its Tarentinotown

Comment: Um, a character being stupid and an asshole is not actually a plot-hole. If it helps, I understood Aldo Raine as a comical and stupid character, too. He is *definitely* not the shiny and all-knowing hero, but I don't think he was ever supposed to be. That doesn't make it a plot-hole, though. That simply means you had the wrong expectations about his character for whatever reasons.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, well he came out victorious and ended WWII that, I think, makes him something of a hero.

Comment: Still no plot-hole, just your expectations and views mismatching with the film.

Comment: Related meta discussion about the question and its wording: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2480/49

Comment: This is a Tarantino thing. A lot of his protagonists are terrible humans--Vic Vega, Jules Winfeld, Marquis Warren. Others, like Django or The Bride, just get a pass because the villains are even worse. But it's also realistic: WWII soldiers were taught to hate and dehumanize their enemies, in America as much as anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I'll attempt to answer.

Initially I thought you were talking about his punishment for carving a swastika into Landa's forehead.  The answer is in the movie.  Raine says that he'll be "chewed out" for this final act of retribution, but that he's been chewed out before and isn't concerned at the prospect.

However, the actual question seems to be "Why wasn't Raine tried for war crimes?"  This is a fair question b/c the Basterds are indeed a special squad, sent in to terrorize the Nazi soldiers, and in doing so, do commit what amount to atrocities.

There are probably many answers one could give, but this is outside the scope of the film.  Tarantino has said that he was making a "Jewish WWII revenge fantasy" and that's basically what he delivers.

It may be instructive to compare Landa to the Basterds, as all are soldiers:

- Landa actively hunts and kills innocent civilians with aplomb, and takes great pleasure in the activity.
- The Inglorious Basterds may kill civilians, such as in the film's finale, but this is in the context of collateral damage, and the civilians in this case can be considered complicit per their association with the Nazi regime.

In the context of the film, the Basterd's mission is perhaps seen to be justified because of the industrial scale atrocities committed by the Nazi regime, and their having started a war that resulted in the deaths of untold millions on all sides of the conflict.

**However, your point that "'All Nazis should be destroyed' is the same thing as stating that 'All Jews should be destroyed.'" is incorrect at a fundamental level:**

The Nazis wanted to destroy all Jews, Gypsies, Slavs, etc. based on their "race" (i.e. the ethnicity they were born into.)  Being part of one of these groups was not a choice, and it extended to women and children.  In other words, genocide.

Affiliation with the Nazi party was a choice, and although I doubt that all German soldiers were enthusiastic supporters of the regime, it was their ill fortune to face conscription in service of the Nazi agenda.  Nevertheless, we are talking about soldiers and politicians, *not* civilians and children.

Comment: While the question seems quite oddly premised and largely opinion-based, I can't see it "promote a political agenda" either. So I wonder what question you actually read.

Comment: He's drawing equivalence between the character of Raine, a soldier, and architects or the Final Solution.  (I'm actually surprised this question is still up--a large number of people would find it fairly offensive.)

Comment: Um...it doesn't really take any political agenda to see Aldo Raine as an overly brutal and slightly ignorant person. You don't have to support his enemies to find him a stupid and non-heroic character really. I little differentiated view of things rather than seeing everything in black and white helps at times. I'm surprised people actually go as far as flagging this (admittedly strange and not particularly good) question as "offensive".

Comment: I do want to say that simply pointing out Raine is a bigot is absolutely fine--he is.  It's just that the questioner goes much farther than than simple point.

Comment: I agree. It is difficult to say that Raines referral to Hitler as a jew hater is a generalization. It is pretty specific. Perhaps the OP thinks all Germans or even simply all German soldiers were Nazis. In any event, the quote states very plainly that it is complicity that indicates their lack of humanity. I guess that is the answer to "is there something I am missing"

Comment: @DukeZhou, No I am not talking about the 'swastika mutilation', I am saying that stating that 'All Nazis should be destroyed' is the same thing as stating that 'All Jews should be destroyed'. I never intended this question to be about politics, I just think that saying that a group of people 'deserves to be destroyed' is inhumane.

Comment: @RobertMugattarov But if you're *not* asking for any consequences to Raine's actions but merely an assessment of his character, then I can't see how this question is not entirely opinion-based. I agree it's not promoting a political agenda, but it's still nothing but asking *"isn't this character actually bad?"*. Yeah, of course he is. So? He is a character that does bad things and thinks the cause justifies the means, in a film that is all about brutality and revenge. What is the discrepancy that needs clarification? Noone ever claimed Raine to be a good person.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, So then Tarantino made a very cruel murderer a hero and the victor of WWII, that is what I think is the hole in the plot, unless, of course, that was done on purpose.

Comment: @RobertMugattarov Indeed he did. But that *is not what a plot hole is*. There's millions of films with anti-heroes and characters like that. That has *nothing* to do with the story's consistency. It just means you thought Raine should be a good person when he isn't. That's not the film's fault at all. There might be a way to turn this into a reasonable question about the film's reception or the intention of its characters' portrayals. But I'm afraid as it stands it just reads as *"Raine is bad, but I want him to be good. What gives"*.

Comment: @RobertMugattarov if that was your actual question, you need to look at how Tarantino, through the character of Clarence Worley in "[True Romance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108399/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm)", explains [Sonny Chiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonny_Chiba)'s character in [Street Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Street_Fighter)--it's not that he's a good guy, it's that he is a bad guy who is badder than actual bad guys.